# Send project id from IPFS Infura Java Android

Tags: ipfs, java, android

In [this tutorial](https://medium.com/coinmonks/setting-up-ipfs-with-android-sdk-a3f621125e47) show how in the following code how to connect to the infura project using android devices, but today this code shows the error "project id is required"

Is there a way to send credentials about projectid and keysecret with the IPFS Library or need use something like HttpUrlConnection?

```
//Implementing IPFS with Infura API's
MultiAddress IPFS_INFURA_URL = new MultiAddress("/dnsaddr/ipfs.infura.io/tcp/5001/https");

//Creating an IPFS client:
IPFS ipfsClient;

//Better to separate declaration and definition as connecting to the client requires a network call
//In Android, a network call cannot be performed on the main thread
//Doing so produces a Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ipfsClient = new IPFS(IPFS_INFURA_URL);
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the project id, you can create one at https://www.infura.io/
Your project ID is also called key in infura.

[image: Infura Api key]

Comment: Yes, i know... but how can send project id using IPFS class in Java?

Comment: MultiAddress IPFS_INFURA_URL = new MultiAddress("/dnsaddr/ipfs.infura.io/tcp/5001/https");
Change the URL by the IPFS url created by infura, 
Create new key -> IPFS

Comment: I tried with the infura url (https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/) send me a error... i will show for you

Comment: .... that is not the the infura url.. you need to generate one with your account

Comment: I have a key created in infura ... When i use MULTIADDRESS send me this error:   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MultiAddress must start with a /

Comment: the error log is pretty self-explanatory, you are copping the IPFS url wrong.
I just can't help you any further, you need to enter a valid IPFS API url. that's the only issue there

Comment: Hi @Mentasuave01 i know, but really don't understand how get my url from painel into infura and use in the MultiAddress

Comment: hi, it's only my question, how send this header of projectid